# How to switch to tab 2 by clicking a button in tab 1?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three tabs, a list on the fragment in tab 1, I want to sent the position of the item I click to fragment two in tab 2 and have the viewpager switch to tab2. I am using an interface to sent the position to the main activity which works fine, invoking a method in fragment two passing it the position is returning a null pointer exception and viewpager is not switching.

The method in MainActivity

```
@Override
public void respond(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"INSIDE MAINACTIVITY AND i = "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("chapters",i);
        PhpFragment f2 = new PhpFragment();
        f2.setArguments(args);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error from MAIN = "+ ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return  new JavaFragment();
            case 1:
                    return new PhpFragment();
            case 2:
                return new NetFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i follow your question... Than you should look into it.

[fragments communication in view pager](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html)

Or another trick is ..

You're using ViewPager and you can take advantage of it. You can add a tag to a ViewPager like this:

**Activity:**

```
pager.setTag("some text");  // pager is a ViewPager object
```

Then you can get this data via ViewGroup in a fragment like this:

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    String result = container.getTag().toString();
    // do something with the result

    return view;
```

You can also setTag() to the container in the fragment.

Another solution (not mentioned here so far) is sending data through SharedPreferences, but I would suggest using tags if possible.